# How to seed a 2D array from an input file by splitting each line into a new row

Tags: perl

I have an input file like this, it looks like a matrix

```
              55 ;           3 ;          21 ;    1 ; 0 ; 0 ; 46
             105 ;           8 ;          21 ;    2 ; 0 ; 0 ; 52
             155 ;          13 ;          21 ;    3 ; 0 ; 0 ; 32
             205 ;          18 ;          21 ;    4 ; 0 ; 0 ; 60
             255 ;          23 ;          21 ;    5 ; 0 ; 0 ; 19
             305 ;          28 ;          21 ;    6 ; 0 ; 0 ; 48
```

How can I read the file to split each line delimited by ';' into a new row of my multidimensional array?

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 64; $i++)  {
    open (FH, "E:/Wessam/Research Group/comparisons/64 PEs/log files/Injector_Log_$i.txt");
    while(<FH>)  {
        @var[$j] = $_;
        $j++;
    }
    close (FH);
}
```

However whenever I print $var[0] or $var[1] it only shows the last line of one of the 64 log files, is there anyway I can have a multidimensional array ?

Comment: welcome to SO ... as always I suggest you battle then show us your code ... in general read the file line by line ... on each line do a split of the string holding the entire line with delimiter of ';' which will return an array which you then insert into your multidimensional array

Comment: Please see [ask] - the point of stack overflow is to help people solve their programming problems. Give it a try yourself (hint: look at `split`) and then ask a question when you get stuck.

Comment: Fist try to solve it from yourself and come back when you stuck somewhere. SO is not a code service provider site. You have to show your efforts first.

Comment: Hint: `@array = split /;/, $line;` you might need to also get rid of some whitespace there.

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Please show us your code. If you don't have code, then Stack Overflow probably isn't the right place for your question.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that Perl doesn't have multi-dimensional arrays. But you can simulate them by having an array that contains references to other arrays. See (the really badly named) [perldoc perllol](https://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html) for details.

Comment: `my @matrix = map [ /\d+/g ], <>`

Comment: @DaveCross: In that sense, no language has multi-dimensional arrays.

Comment: @Borodin: That seems entirely possible.But are you sure there's no language that has true 2D arrays at least? I can't think of one.

Comment: @DaveCross: I'm unsure what a "true 2D" array would look like without 2D memory. There needs to be an implementation (mapping) layer with linear memory. Much like complex numbers.

Comment: @DaveCross I think perllol is always good for a quick laugh... ;)

Comment: @ScottStensland I have tried these lines of code, thank you for your motivation!

Comment: @DaveCross I have tried these lines of code, thank you for your motivation!

Comment: Your code has a loop which pulls in a set of files ... I suggest you get working the parse of a single input file then tackle the loop later

Answer (score 1):

Some comments on your code:

```
# Professional Perl programmers rarely use this
# "C-style" for loop. Use foreach instead.
for ($i = 0; $i < 64; $i++)  {
    # Please use three-arg open() and lexical filehandles.
    # Always check the return value from open().
    open (FH, "E:/Wessam/Research Group/comparisons/64 PEs/log files/Injector_Log_$i.txt");
    while(<FH>)  {
        # This should be $var[$j].
        # But it's better written using push().
        # And you're not splitting your data.
        @var[$j] = $_;
        $j++;
    }
    close (FH);
}
```

I would write it like this:

```
my $dir = 'E:/Wessam/Research Group/comparisons/64 PEs/log files';
my @data;
foreach my $i (0 .. 63) {
   my $file = "$dir/Injector_Log_$i.txt";
   open my $log_fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";

   while (<$log_fh>) {
     # Match sequences of digits - \d+
     # Capture those matches - (...)
     # Find *all* matches - /g
     # Create an anonymous array = [ ... ]
     # Push a reference to that array onto @data
     push @data, [ /(\d+)/g ];
   }

   # No need to explicitly close the filehandle, as it
   # is automatically closed when $log_fh goes out of scope.
}
```

Also, I'm guessing that your code doesn't include `use strict` and `use warnings`. You should alway use these.